# Table of contents of Jupyter notebook makes cell not center

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[image]

Here is the one sample that cell is in center.

[image]

However, when i make table of content enable, cell goes to attach to table of content.

[image]

I realized that when i move table of content, cell is also moving.

They are attached each other.

However, i want to make them independently separate.

I moved new computer and installed jupyter notebook as below.

Moreover, when i open jupyter notebook, table of content always goes up as below.

[image]

I have to always manually drop down table of content with mouse.

How to solve this problem?

[image]